# Socket timeout not working, InputStream read blocks

Tags: java, sockets, block

I have problem with socket inputstream reading.
Before reading I set timeout for HttpClient

```
connectionManager.getParams().setSoTimeout(1000*10);
connectionManager.getParams().setConnectionTimeout(1000*10);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(connectionManager);
```

Try to read response stream and instead SocketTimeoutException I getting block on read() method.

```
    client.executeMethod(method);
    InputStream stream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        int read;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            baos.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            baos.close();
            stream.close();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I read input stream without blocks and why soTimeout not working ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was resolved. I added thread monitor that invoke stop method of thread reading response.